# How to count microstates in quantum statistical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

According to the fundamental postulate of statistical mechanics (as far as I know it), we take the (classical) probability for a system to be in any of its microstates to be equal (if the system is in equilibrium and isolated). My question is, how do we count the number of microstates? From what I can see, the number of microstates is usually taken to be the number of linearly independant energy eigenstates of the Hamiltonian for that particular value of energy. However, I don't see why this is the 'number' of microstates. Are we supposed to imagine the microcanonical ensemble as a macroscopic quantum system for which we have measured the energy? In that case the system could be in any one of an (uncountably) infinite number of linear superpositions of its degenerate energy eigenstates. In other words the state vector could be be any vector at all in the degenerate energy eigenspace.

So why are we allowed to count the number of states as the number of linearly independant energy eigenstates, when we don't know that the system would even be in an eigenstate (but rather only in some linear combination)? And as a direct consequence of this method of counting, it seems we assign a non-zero probability only for the system to be in energy eigenstates, and ignore the possibility that it could be in a superposition.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. I just wanted to express admiration for a clearly written and interesting first post :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Summary: the question "what is the probability of state $|\psi \rangle$" is the wrong question to ask, because it's experimentally unobservable. What you really care about is the results of measurements, and the number of possible different measurement outcomes is equal to the number of microstates.

---

Consider a bunch of noninteracting spin 1/2 particles in thermal equilibrium, and look at a single spin inside.

On the classical level, at thermal equilibrium, the spin of this particle should be a vector with random direction. Now we might ask, on the quantum level, what's the state of this particle?

However, this is the wrong question to ask. Given *any* spinor $|\psi \rangle$, it's possible to find an axis $\mathbf{n}$ so that $|\psi\rangle$ is the positive eigenstate of $S_{\mathbf{n}}$, i.e. the spin is definitely up along $\mathbf{n}$. So individual elements of the Hilbert space are insufficient to represent a thermal state.

Instead, we need to do the same thing we did in the classical case: replace the state of a system (i.e. $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{p})$ classically and $|\psi \rangle$ in quantum) with a probability distribution over those states. One such probability distribution is
$$50\% \text{ chance } |\uparrow \rangle, \quad 50\% \text{ chance } |\downarrow \rangle.$$
The miraculous thing is that this distribution is rotationally invariant! That is, the distributions
$$50\% \text{ chance } | \mathbf{n} \rangle, \quad 50\% \text{ chance } |-\mathbf{n}\rangle$$
are indistinguishable by measurement for any direction $\mathbf{n}$. Every spin measurement of any $\mathbf{n}$ ensemble, along *any* direction $\mathbf{m}$, gives a 50/50 result.

This tells us that the correct description of a thermal ensemble of quantum particles can't be an assignment of probabilities to quantum states, because such a construction isn't unique: there are many probability distributions that are experimentally indistinguishable. (The quantity that corresponds to probability distributions "up to distinguishability" is called the density matrix $\rho$.)

---

With this setup, the answers to your questions are:

- Why don't we consider superpositions? We do! You can't directly ask "what is the probability the system is in state $|\psi \rangle$", because this is not an experimentally observable quantity, as explained above. But you can perform a measurement of an operator $\hat{A}$ with eigenvector $|\psi \rangle$ and eigenvalue $\lambda$, and there's some probability you get $\lambda$.
- Why do we count microstates? This is the dimension of our Hilbert space, or more physically, the number of different numbers you can get while measuring $\hat{A}$. In the example above, the probability of getting $\lambda$ is $1/2$ where $2$ is the number of microstates. We aren't privileging the spin up or spin down states, because you get a 50/50 chance for any spin operator $S_{\mathbf{n}}$.
- Why do we count specifically energy eigenstates? This is just for convenience. What we really want is the dimension of the Hilbert space, and $\hat{H}$ is often easy to deal with/reason about.

Comment: This is a good answer, +1. The only thing I would add is some discussion of *why* the density matrix is the right thing to use for a thermal state. Since that's discussed elsewhere though, a link would be nice.

Comment: _number of different numbers you can get_ — but it isn't the dimension of our Hilbert space if there are degenerate states, since the latter is the more like number of _"usually different"_ numbers you can get.

Comment: @Ruslan Mhm, agreed. I skimmed over that to save a little bit of space; one can also read the phase as "the maximum number of different numbers you can get".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1. I am still having some trouble following the argument though. What exactly is the motivation for choosing the mixed state (and by mixed state I mean classical probability distribution over quantum states, correct me if I'm wrong) 50% up and 50% down? Is it simply that this state is rotationally invariant and hence doesn't 'privilege' any particular direction, and is in that sense fair? If that is the case I have trouble deciding how to choose my probability distribution in cases other than spin 1/2 particles (ideal quantum gas for example).

Comment: Also, very sorry but I don't follow why I should be interested in counting 'the number of different numbers you can get while measuring A'. In classical stat mech, the microcanonical distribution is a uniform distribution over a constant energy surface in phase space, and I can motivate this by saying that we know the energy, but nothing more, hence we should weight every point in phase space with that energy equally. I'm having trouble finding analogous motivation for the quantum counting procedure. Come to think of it, I feel I'm not following some central points in your argument!

Comment: @Andrew There are a lot of questions here. Am I right in saying that your central concern is that "50% $|\uparrow \rangle$, 50% $|\downarrow \rangle$" feels unnatural, compared to the alternative of "uniform distribution over all $|\mathbf{n} \rangle$"?

Comment: In principle, there's nothing stopping you from choosing that distribution. However, there's a key difference between classical and quantum phase space. In classical phase space, you can, in principle, measure the phase space distribution $\rho(x, p)$. But you _can't_ measure the distribution $\rho(\mathbf{n})$ for the quantum spins.

Comment: This is exemplified by the fact that all "50% $|\mathbf{n} \rangle$, 50% $|-\mathbf{n} \rangle$" ensembles are experimentally indistinguishable. (This is basically that old mantra, 'measurement changes the state of a system', which holds for quantum measurements but not classical ones.) So asking for $\rho(x, p)$ is very natural in the classical case but unnatural in the quantum case.

Comment: Part of the problem is also that I'm not giving a _proof_. In quantum statistical mechanics, saying that the density matrix is proportional to the identity (i.e. choosing the 'unbiased ensembles' I displayed) is the very postulate you start with, analogously to how 'uniform distribution in phase space' is the starting postulate for classical statistical mechanics. So my answer isn't proving anything -- it's showing why that postulate is a natural choice.

Comment: As for your question about how microstate counting comes in: suppose we accept the above postulate. Then if we measure any operator $\hat{O}$ with nondegenerate eigenvalues, every measurement result is equally likely. Then every result must have probability $1/n$ where $n$ is the number of microstates, so the density matrix is $I/n$. That's how the number of microstates must get involved.

Comment: @knzhou You're right I am asking a lot of questions - I suppose the central issue for me is a motivation from the 'ground up' of why we do quantum stat mech the way we do. I think I get the logic of how we do it classically, and I'd like to see it analogously done in QM. That's probably beyond the scope of my original question, perhaps I should read up more about this before I go on - I was thinking Tolman but I'm worried it's a bit outdated, do you have recommendations?

Comment: Yes I suppose what I would have thought most 'natural' would have been to give equal weight using some probability distribution to every single state vector (and there are a continuous infinity of these) in the degenerate eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue E. That would be my 'microcanonical ensemble' for energy E. Am I right in saying that I should instead think of a probability distribution over states constructed such that each measurement outcome is equally likely? That seems strange - does this apply to every single observable I care to measure?

Comment: @knzhou This answer is interesting, but I didn't quite follow the reasoning of why the indistinguishability of uniform distributions means we can't define ensembles this way. I have also posted a related question, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293745/what-physical-principle-determines-microstates-in-quantum-mechanics, in which I discuss this counterfactual explicitly. If you feel like you are able to answer this question too I would be thankful.

Comment: I'm not too sure about this, but don't we talk specifically about the energy eigenstates because they are time independent (upto a phase, of course) and when we write the density matrix the off-diagonal terms rotate their phase at a very high rate? I'm doing my first classical statistics course, so I just have a vague idea. If someone could clarify, that'd be wonderful.

Comment: @NandagopalM Sure, that's a reasonable way to argue that the thermal density matrix ends up diagonal in the energy basis. But that doesn't stop you from considering the thermal density matrix in other bases, such as the position basis.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, independently of the ensamble, if you want a density matrix that describes a state of equilibrium, then it has to commute with the hamiltonian (see Liouville theorem for QM). This means that both the density matrix and the hamiltonian can be diagonalized in the same basis and, thus, the system is indeed in a statistichal mixture of energy eigenstates.

Now, if the system is in the microcanonical ensemble then "counting microstates" means counting how many non-zero terms does the density matrix has in its diagonal. That's why you don't take into account other possible states like superpositions of energy eigenstates. You need to count the diagonal terms of the density matrix written in a particular basis that diagonalizes the hamiltonian too.

Comment: Please see my question physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293745/… for how counting superpositions of eigenstates (ie off diagonal elements) still results in stationary equilibrium state but does not give the correct QM answer.

Comment: What a nice answer it is! After studying classical and quantum microcanonical ensemble I was solely confused by the counting procedure: where is my $\pho$ etc.! Now I see that connection.

Comment: @P. C. Spaniel: Is the number of microstates = the number of diagonal terms in the density matrix? or, the number of **nonzero** diagonal elements in the density matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The foundations of statistical mechanics are sometimes easier to understand for classical finite-state systems, such as a lattice of classical two-state systems (bits) used to model spins in a magnetic material.  With $n$ bits you have $2^n$ distinct possible states.  If there are macroscopic constraints such as external fields biasing the probabilities for each bit to be a 0 or 1, the effective number of bits is smaller.

Quantum Statistical Mechanics can be thought of as generalizing this idea, again counting the finite number of perfectly distinct (mutually orthogonal) states that can be constructed with given macroscopic constraints.  This is the same as the effective dimensionality of the Hilbert space, since a basis is a set of mutually orthogonal states.

The viewpoint that quantum systems generalize classical finite-state ones is familiar if you've thought about quantum computers, which include classical computation as a special case.  A more traditional view might be that the finite count of distinct states is an invariant that survives decoherence, which creates a classical probability distribution over a particular finite set of distinct quantum states defined by the decoherence process.