# Expression of density operator for Microcanonical ensemble

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, probability, density-operator

Consider a quantum microcanonical ensemble,with a fixed energy $E$.

In Greiner, the expression for its density operator is given as.
$\displaystyle\hat\rho=\frac{\delta(\hat H-E.1)}{Tr(\delta(\hat H-E.1))}\tag{1}$

Numerator, I can understand. If we have the information that the energy of Microcanonical ensemble is E, then we have to take $\hat H=E$ and thus numerator yields identity matrix otherwise zero matrix.

In classical statistical mechanics, the expression for probability density for Microcanonical ensemble is given as
$\rho(E)=\frac{\delta (H-E)}{\Omega(E)}\tag{2}$

The denominator of $(2)$ suggests that $\Omega$ is all the possible microstates having energy $E$.

But if we see $(1)$, $Tr(\delta(\hat H-E.1))$ is basically the dimensions of $\hat H$ operator which is basically the number of degenerate eigen kets having energy eigen value $E$.
So, the denominator captures only the number of degenerate eigenstates not all the states with energy $E$. Any superposition of these eigenstates also yields a state having energy $E$.
So,if we consider these eigen kets to be the bases of Hilbert space, then all the states which lies on the unit sphere of this Hilbert space will have energy $E$.

So, in the denominator of $(1)$ why are we only counting the eigenstates of $\hat H$ with energy $E$, not all the possible wavefunctions?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280469/how-to-count-microstates-in-quantum-statistical-mechanics), check also the links therein.

Comment: The Tr counts the dimension of the Hilbert space spanned by energy eigenstates with $E$. There are uncountably infinite many states in that Hilbert space (or in any Hilbert space with dim > 1), so the number of states is meaningless.