# Infinite number of microstates in quantum description?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

The following argument comes from Griffiths QM second edition.

Suppose we're in a 1D infinite square well with 3 distinct particles. The total energy, then, is
$$
E = E_A + E_B + E_C = \frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2m a^2} (n_A^2 + n_B^2 + n_C^2).
$$
Let's fix $E = 363(\pi^2 \hbar^2/ 2ma^2)$. This is equivalent to saying $n_A^2 + n_B^2 + n_C^2 = 363 $, and there are several possible values $(n_A,n_B,n_c)$ could take:
$$
\begin{align*} &(11,11,11) \\ &(13,13,5), \quad (13,5,13), \quad (5,13,13) \\ &(1,1,19), \quad (1,19,1), \quad (19,1,1) \\ &(5,7,17), \quad (5,17,7), \quad (7,5,17), \quad (7,17,5), \quad (17,5,7), \quad (17,7,5).\end{align*}
$$
In this case, $\Omega$, the number of microstates, is presumably 13.

The thing I'm confused about is, since these are all degenerate  eigenstates of $\hat H |\psi\rangle = E|\psi\rangle$, where $|\psi\rangle$ is the state of the system, is there not a whole degenerate subspace of linear combinations of these basis states? In that case, wouldn't $\Omega$ be infinity? Perhaps $\Omega$ really counts the dimensionality of this subspace, which is definitely 13?

Furthermore, we could choose a different orthonormal basis for this degenerate subspace. Why is this the natural basis to use? (It certainly seems the most natural, but is there a mathematical reason for it?)

Comment: I think that has been asked before here on PSE (several times)...

Comment: @TobiasFünke I've seen a question like this, but the answer just said something like, there are infinitely many microstates for classical mechanics, but quantum mechanics, therefore done. Can you find any question that has been asked before that addresses my queries? Thanks!

Comment: What about [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280469/)?

Comment: @TobiasFünke I see, that is pretty closely related. Should I remove my post then? (I'm relatively new here, apologies)

Comment: No, don't do that. Instead, we can label this post as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count microstates in quantum statistical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280469/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The microstates counted in statistical mechanics arguments all have to be *mutually orthogonal* (in Hilbert space). This fact ought to be made clear in the early part of any textbook on the subject, but often it is left a bit unclear. (The similar result in classical statistical mechanics is that we count regions of some given volume in phase space).

Comment: ...and, as such, we'd say in the case of the OP that $\Omega=\mathrm{dim}H_E$, where $H_E$ is the subspace of eigenstates of $H$ with energy $E$.

Comment: yes it can equally well be stated like that

Comment: That's fair enough, but is the above the natural basis to choose?